# how to use ajax.beginform with foreach and model to create button for each li inside a partialview ul list? (the buttons are there to remove items/li)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an mvc project and in it I am using foreachinside a partial view to fill an ul list in the view . My foreach collection is a list of model and I want to create a button for each model/li element that submits the current model to a PartialViewResult which then will delete the model from databse. So I try something like this:

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.Lang_User
@{ WebApplication6.Models.Entities db = new WebApplication6.Models.Entities();
 List<WebApplication6.Models.Lang_User> langlist=db.Lang_User.Where(x => x.UserID ==Model.UserID).ToList();
    }
{ 
@foreach (WebApplication6.Models.Lang_User item in langlist)
{using (Ajax.BeginForm("DilSil", new AjaxOptions())) {


    <li id="@item.ID" class="list-group-item">@item.Languages.Language <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"></button></li>
    }
}
```

But now i need to make something inside ajaxforms. When i submit one of the forms in ul list. It must submit the @item so is there a way to do it?

edit1: Delete PartialViewResult

```
 public PartialViewResult DilSil(Lang_User dil)
        {
            db.Lang_User.Remove(dil);
            db.SaveChanges();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return PartialView("_DilPartial", dil);
        }
```

Comment: How does your Delete action method looks like ? Also what does this mean **When i submit one of the forms in ul list. It must submit the @item so is there a way to do it**  ?

Comment: now the thing i post is "_DilPartial" partial view my delete action looks like this

Comment: so i create multiple forms and submit buttons in foreach right what i want is when i click on of the buttons which is inside of the ajax.beginform i want it to submit the item using that beginform

Comment: so what i want is to every ajax.beginform i created have a model and a button inside and when i click the button it submits the model

Comment: Create a hidden input with value as `item.ID`. In the controller, remove `Lang_User` for that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is, to send the unique Id of the entity in the form post. To do that, Keep the id in an input field, which is hidden inside the form. The input element name should match with your parameter name. When user clicks on the button, the form data will be submitted, including the hidden input

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DilSil", new AjaxOptions() { }))
{
    <li id="@item.ID" class="list-group-item">
        This is @item.ID
        <input type="hidden" value="@item.ID" name="id" />

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button>
    </li>
}
```

Now in your action method, read the id, get the entity and delete it. You can probably return the list of current data (read it again from db) and pass that and update the UI using  `UpdateTargetId` and `InsertionMode` attributes or return a JSON response which you can handle in your `OnSuccess` handler

In your case, your li item id is same is the id of the entity .So you can return that information back to the client and the `OnSuccess` handler method can delete that element from the DOM

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DilSil(int id)
{
   var dil=db.Lang_User.Find(id);
   db.Lang_User.Remove(dil);
   db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { status = "success" , id=id });
 }
```

Now add an `OnSuccess` handler to your `AjaxOptions` when using `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method to render the form. This will be a javascript function which will be called after the ajax call is done. The response from server will be passed to this function.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DilSil", new AjaxOptions() {  OnSuccess = "DeleteDone" }))
{
    <li id="@item.ID" class="list-group-item">
        This is @item.ID
        <input type="hidden" value="@item.ID" name="id" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button>
    </li>
}
```

Now define the javascript method which reads the json response and delete the li item

```
function DeleteDone(a, b, c) {
    if (a.status === 'success') {
        $("#" + a.id).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so you say i submit the id and delete using it ok let me try real fast

Comment: it creates the buttons but when i click on them it goes to my controller and returns does not enter my dilsil partialviewresult but it gave me an idea what if i put the whole ul inside a ajax.beginform can i change the input value with button click?

Comment: See my updated answer. Ideally  there is no point in returning the partial view for the deleted item. Instead you may simply reload the list or delete the item from the UI. The updated answer has code to delete the li item form the UI.

Comment: i am returning partialview because it returns me the li list i need to refresh it without refreshing my main view i am trying the updated version

Comment: so if you remove the item from UI, which is going to be similar to what the list will be

Comment: but6 will it refresh the ul list in my main view?

Comment: It removes the li item from the view. Why don't you try it ?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult' this comes up as error when i change partialviewresult's return

Comment: Sorry! it was a copy-paste mistake from your question. Change it to `ActionResult`

Comment: same problem it never enters in the actionresult does not delete anything and it didn't remove them from the list either

Comment: When you click on the button, Is it making the ajax call ? Check your browser network tab

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'dil' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DilSil(Int32)' in 'WebApplication6.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parametre adÄ±: parameters

Comment: In my answer, my action method parameter is int variable called `id`. So make sure that your hidden input element name is same. Just follow the code in answer as it is and it will work.

Comment: ok ty for that it does delete but it does not remove from li i think i couldn't do the function part quite right

Comment: hold on do i write the function inside partial view or in my main view?

Comment: You have to add the `DeleteDone` js function inside a script block inside your main view, or add it to an external js file which you included in that page. Also make sure you have the `OnSuccess` handler defined.

Comment: so if i add this inside my main view it should work right?
<script>

    function DeleteDone(a, b, c) {
        if (a.status === 'success') {
            $("#" + a.id).remove();
        }
    }

</script>

}

Comment: Your post title is confusing. I suggest you to edit it to be some thing more generic and clear so others can be benefited from it.

Comment: how to use ajax.beginform with foreach and create button for each li inside a partialview ul list? what do you think still complicated?

Comment: it was to delete i will add that too